# Replace smiles with images in NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsstring

I have a list of `Emoji` entities and each of the has property `codes` and I want to check string (`"]:-)"`) if it contains any of them and then replace smile with an image.

```
for (Emoji *emoji in self.emojis) {
    for (NSString *code in emoji.codes) {
        NSString *pattern = [NSRegularExpression escapedPatternForString:code];
        NSRegularExpression *regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:nil];

        NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:[sourceString string] options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [sourceString length])];

        [matches enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult * _Nonnull aResult, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
            NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
            [attachment setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:emoji.image]];

            NSAttributedString *replacement = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment];
            [sourceString replaceCharactersInRange:[aResult range] withAttributedString:replacement];
        }];
    }
}
```

The problem is that smile with code `]:-)` contains `:-)` and my method replacing it with next: *bracket* `]` + `[image]` for `:-)`, it is because `:-)` goes first in list.

How can I check for exact string?

I've tried:
`]:-/)`, `\\b]:-/)\\b`, `/^]:-/)$/`

Maybe there is better solution to make this working.

Comment: Would it be possible to post an example of a string containing these smiles?

Comment: sure, it is just a smile

Comment: If it is just a smile, then you could just have a dictionary where the keys would be the smiles and values would be the images (or image names). Then you could just do something like `let image: UIImage? = smiles[smile]`, plus having the benefit of constant lookup times.

Comment: Each emoji object can have few codes. For example, happy = ":)", ":-)" etc.

Comment: Quick fix idea: don't use a `NSDictionary`, use a NSArray of Single Dictionary (or small objects with a property "stringEmoji" and another one "imageName". Sort it in a way that "smaller" emojis are at the end, the one that can be included in multiple ones.

Comment: @landonandrey This is not a problem. You can have multiple keys with the same value... (e.g. `[ ":)" : "happy" , ":-)" : "happy" ]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly your current structure:

```
@interface Emoji : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *image; //I'd expect a UIImage there and not an image name
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *codes;
@end
```

A possible solution is instead to use a single couple of values: imageName/code

```
@interface Emoji : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *image; //I'd expect a UIImage there and not an image name
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *code;
@end
```

`self.emojis` will have plenty of `Emoji` object that may have the same image name for different code, but an advantage of doing that is this little trick:
Sort `self.emojis` in a way that "smaller" emojis are at the end. So you'll replace first only the "lengthy" ones and the the smaller ones.

```
self.emojis = [arrayOfSingleEmojis sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Emoji * _Nonnull emoji1, Emoji * _Nonnull emoji2) {
    NSUInteger length1 = [[emoji1 code] length];
    NSUInteger length2 = [[emoji2 code] length];
    return [@(length2) compare:@(length1)]; //Or reverse length1 & length2, I never know, I always have to test, but I think it's the correct one
}];
```

So in your current case: `]:-)` will be replace before `:-)` so you should have `<imageFor:">:-)"]` instead of `]<imageFor:":-)>`

Comment: I saw that you used my answer on the other related question for your code (to replace emojis text by images: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51516190/1801544). I didn't test it, glad to see it works and especially that it helped you.

Comment: yes, I've used your answer for question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51515859/change-string-with-picture-in-swift/51516190#51516190